# Motion GIF for background

Tags: react-native, animated-gif

First thing to mention, I'm only starting with React-Native, that being said I wrote few apps for native Android, so the understanding is there.

At the current stage I'm prototyping the app and I was wondering how the-pro`s would go about implementing [the following motion GIF](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/32512/screenshots/3556927/waves_background_growing_data_by_gleb.gif) for the background.

The only option I see is to compile the following GIF for portrait/landscape and for for all the device sizes I want to support. That of course is a lot of effort.

Any other option?

Can GIF scale down and keep it's motion and quality? If I compile it quite big, let's say to cover all devices below desktop, would it scale down to mobile and keep it's quality?

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using GIFV format or WebM format instead.